# Перевод логической формулы на язык Pascal

Tags: pascal

Правильно ли я перевёл логическую формулу на язык Pascal?

[image]

```
if (y div k=0)and not(x div k=0) then
```

Или скорее наоборот, правильно ли я перевёл выражение на языке pascal в логическую формулу?

Comment: Я, так понимаю, должен заменить тождество на равно, чтобы формула соответствовала коду?

Comment: Тип integer (чуть по привычке не поставил точку с запятой) )

Comment: А возможно ли упростить формулу?

Comment: Похоже, что правильно. Упростить - вряд-ли - тут всего 2 логических оператора.

Comment: Всем спасибо.

Comment: Зависит от нотации, может у Вас равенство так извращенно решили обозначить.

А еще меня смущает практический смысл выражения вида y div k = 0 (⌊y∕k⌋ = 0). Оно будет истинным только при y = 0. Может быть там остаток от деления (`mod`) имелся в виду?

Comment: @drdaeman, я думаю, что здесь [≡](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_bar) обозначает конгруэнтость, как в ![](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/math/3/c/8/3c8c79012aeebb48b9128a4011e231ad.png)

Comment: Кстати, да, про этот вариант я забыл. Похоже на правду.

Comment: Чорт, уже второй раз пропускаю букву в слове, кончающемся на ...ность, простите :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в формуле тождество (≡), вместо равенства (=), то ситуация зависит от типов, и, скорее всего сводится к `false`. :)

Но, подозреваю, что это просто такая извращенная нотация. Если там равенство — да, вроде как, верно.